# weird Internal Server Error - no error log produced

Tags: ajax

I'm facing a weird issue with a Wordpress installation and I'm not sure how to proceed further. I've developed a simple AJAX endpoint only available for logged in users, which returns the details of a custom post type associated with the user. Example:

```
function get_return_request_detail() {
    $returnRequestId = (isset($_POST['return_request_id'])) ? $_POST['return_request_id'] : '';
    if(empty($returnRequestId)) {
        echo json_encode("missing parameter");
        wp_die();
    }

    $results = get_post_meta($returnRequestId);
    $meta = unserialize($results["_meta"][0]);

    if($results["_field_user_id"][0] == get_current_user_id()) {

        ... logic ...

        echo json_encode($data);
    } else {
        echo json_encode("unauthorized");
    }
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_get_return_request_detail', 'get_return_request_detail');
```

The endpoint works fine and I retrieve the data correctly. An example on how I call it:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
                action:'get_return_request_detail',
                return_request_id: id,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
        },
    });
```

The problem is that as soon as I switch to another page the whole front-end starts returning an error:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to
> inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
> trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I've tried enabling both debug and debug_log but I still receive the same message with nothing being written in the log. To enable it I've just added in the `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

The weird behaviour is that, in order to make the front-end work again, I just need to visit an Admin page and the error disappears. My questions are:

1. Is there any way to have a more detailed error log for this issue?
2. Do you have any idea on what could be possibly causing it? Something related to admin-ajax?

What I've tried so far, with no results:

1. Check Wordpress core file permission;
2. Replace core files with a fresh installation;
3. Followed [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/307689/209337) in order to enable error logging for admin-ajax.php (no results);
4. Disable caching / security plugins;
5. Disable Server Side caching (Dynamic Cache & Memcached);
6. Check error logs on Server (the error produces no log);

Thanks

Comment: Replace `exit;` with `wp-die();` in your AJAX function.

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried with `wp_die()` and also with `wp_send_json()` but the error keeps occurring

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/383095/strange-behavior-random-http-error-500-fixed-by-visiting-permalinks-settings-pa) which describes the same issue i'm facing. The accepted solution didn't work for me, but after a bit more research I've found [this solution](https://wpml.org/errata/htaccess-is-rewritten-with-language-folder/) from WPML.

I've noticed that after calling the endpoint the `.htaccess` was getting rewritten, this part:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^en/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/wp-login.php /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
```

gets rewritten as:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /it/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^en/wp-login.php /it/wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/wp-login.php /it/wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^de/wp-login.php /it/wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^it/wp-login.php /it/wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /it/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
```

After applying the suggested solution from WPML:

```
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'fix_rewritebase');
function fix_rewritebase($rules){
    $home_root = parse_url(home_url());
    if ( isset( $home_root['path'] ) ) {
        $home_root = trailingslashit($home_root['path']);
    } else {
        $home_root = '/';
    }
 
    $wpml_root = parse_url(get_option('home'));
    if ( isset( $wpml_root['path'] ) ) {
        $wpml_root = trailingslashit($wpml_root['path']);
    } else {
        $wpml_root = '/';
    }
 
    $rules = str_replace("RewriteBase $home_root", "RewriteBase $wpml_root", $rules);
    $rules = str_replace("RewriteRule . $home_root", "RewriteRule . $wpml_root", $rules);
 
    return $rules;
}
```

I can see that the values for `RewriteBase /` and `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` don't get updated anymore and the Internal Server Error disappears.

In my case **I guess** the issue was caused by developing the website in a language and then changing it and transferring the website. I'll contact WPML to let them know about the issue, also I still don't get what's causing the rewrite of the `.htaccess` after calling the endpoint.